# For loop to access array elements of index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am trying to compare the names of the element at the current index and the previous index for each element to determine if they are the same name so I don't print out the name twice.

Unfortunately, trying to access the array element using `array[i]` doesn't work, but if I hard-code an index or just print out the index, it works fine so I'm not sure where it's messing up.

I need to be able to access the previous element though so I can't use other loops so only suggest something where I can access the previous element in the array.

```
<% for i in 1..count %>
    <% if array[i].count > 1 %>
        <% if array[i-1].name == array[i].name %>
           <%= array[i].name %> 
           <%= array[7].name %> 
           <%= i %>     
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Does anyone know the correct way to access an element in an array?

Comment: Stylistically, and idiomatically, we don't use `for` loops in Ruby. Instead, use `each`. `for` leaks the intermediate value into the variable space which is considered sloppy coding, and it is too easy to try to access elements in an array that don't exist, which `each` can't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, you can do it like this:

```
array.each_with_index do |el, i|
  prev_el = array[i-1]  #will be nil for the first element
  next_el = array[i+1]  #will be nil for the last element
  if prev_el && el.name == prev_el.name
    #name same as previous
  end
  if next_el && el.name == next_el.name
    #name same as next
  end
end
```

You should avoid index-based array access for loops, not because they don't work but because there are much nicer and more readable ways of looping through arrays in Ruby.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as correct, or even just mark it up :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it if your list is sorted and all you care about is printing names:

```
<% array.map(&:name).uniq.each do |name| %>
  <%= name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep in mind that you are using Ruby, and the motto of Ruby is "**Do More in Less Work**".

You can use `uniq` to filter out all similar elements, then iterate through them to do whatever you want to do. `uniq` works like this:

```
a = [ "a", "a", "b", "b", "c" ]
a.uniq   # => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

This should do it all what you tried to do:

```
<% array.uniq.each do |obj| %>
  <%= obj.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to comment on your suggested edit Sharvy, so I'm going to reply here:
1. You need the `map(&:name)` because the OP's code suggests you have to call name on the array elements to get the name.
2. `uniq` may be overkill if he actually only cares about consecutive appearances of the identical name. If "Sharvy" appears at position 1 and position 10, uniq will remove the one at position 10, but his problem description doesn't describe that behavior (unless the assumption is that his array is sorted).

Comment: i solved it, but my array was sorted... i could not use uniq for my particular issue because i needed a unique name, color, etc but not an entirely unique element.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of another way of doing this:

```
grouped = array.group_by(&:name)
```

Now you have a hash where each key is a unique name and the corresponding value is all the array elements with that name.  So next you can do stuff like

```
#list of names in alphabetical order
grouped.keys.sort

#get one element for each unique name
grouped.map{|name,els| els.first}

#print out how many you have for each name
grouped.each{|name, els| puts "#{name.inspect} => #{els.size} elements"};false
```